# iOS 11 SDK update – wrong Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

After updating my app from iOS 10 to iOS 11 SDK I started receiving messages from users, that localization after update has been broken.

There are a lot of user who complain but only one provided me details about that issue:

- region: Brazil
- languages: Portuguese, English
- in app: Japanese

Some app info:

- App is translated into English (`en`), Japanese, etc. and has no Portuguese
- `Use base internationalization` ticked, but it doesn't matter, I don't use it
- `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` is set to `en`

Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't change anything from localizable files, just disabled `Use base internationalization` and released new version – complaints are disappear.

Anyway new release helped me avoid that problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like bugs about i18n problem. How do you collect user's log ? Or, how do you figure out what happen ?

My app supports 5 languages. For those un-supported language, it will use `Base.lproj` directory as default.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't user logs, but have a full mailbox with localization complainings. It happened only after iOS 11 SDK migration.